# Why is my answer downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

Why was my answer so bad [on this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230552/the-best-tools-money-can-buy/2230640#2230640)?

In my opinion the answer was okay. But it seems like most people disagree with me.

Help me become a better Overflower. :-)

I'm really baffled, as evidenced by the [revision history of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts//2230640/revisions). I think the answer is OK. Sure, it has no direct connection to JEE, but the question was rather open. I referred to a now deleted part of the question:

> If you have the chance working with the best tools (including free/open source), what were they? Could you live without them? How did they improve your life and your productivity?

Is Jira directly connected to JEE? Source Control? Why are those and a task control is not?

Comment: You should typically ask this as a comment to your answer, not as a brand new question on meta.

Comment: Woosh, I did it again... 

Why am I always colliding with the common sense? It must be me, isn't it?

I call this the wikipedia-effect. It's sold as "open, free, open-minded" but sometimes it's controlled by some who think they have a better idea of "open, free, open-minded" than others. Don't you think so?

Comment: even the most open-minded folk need social norms to maintain some order.  if you don't grok those social norms, they might not seem that open-minded.  yaDDu' IHqu' vIghaj'be' taH'a'?

Comment: What was that? 

"yaDDu' IHqu' vIghaj'be' taH'a'?" :-)

Comment: I think ~quack is trying to summon Cthulhu.  Or maybe Hastur.  But probably Cthulhu.

Comment: Me don't like Cthulhu being summoned in my questions... or Hastur...

Comment: If I could change my display name, I'd totally go with Cthulhu

Comment: " *taH! pagh taH'be'!*  you have not experienced Shakespeare until you have read him in the original Klingon."   ... and you call yourselves geeks...

Comment: +1, because this _is_ a good question ... the right answer is below courtesy David Thornley: read comments to understand why you were up-/down-voted.  Like this one.  Huh.  Very meta ...

Answer (score 3):

Reading the comments on the question is normally a much better way to find out than asking on MSO.  The comments are likely left by people who downvoted you and are explaining why.  Try to understand what the commenters are saying.  In this case, you seem to be arguing with them, not trying to understand.

You may or may not agree with reasons why people downvote you, but trying to refute their reasons and coming to MSO for more reasons is probably not productive.

Answer (score 1):

> Profilers, designers, frameworks,
>   graphical components, and other tools
>   are welcome.

He said "other tools", but I think that even with this you were waaaay off topic.

Comment: Exactly. If we start like this, we can say also "a good and fast computer helps me with JEE", "a good chair helps me", "having a calm environment helps too", "having no digesting troubles helps me with JEE"

Comment: @Gnoupi: "having a calm environment helps too : This is even a part of the mentioned Joel-Test.

But I got the idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be terribly concerned about down-votes on an answer in CW. It is a discussion thread, people will disagree with it. There is a reason rep is not affected by wiki discussions. There will be disagreements and as a result of those disagreements, there are down-voted responses.

Otherwise, it seems your overall track record represents a favorable following in the community wiki. I wouldn't think that 4 down-votes on this should bother you.

Answer (score 0):

@bitschnau I don't think your answer deserves 4 downvotes, but as dboarman already says, people read the non-Java related part of your answer, and downvotes are given easier in CW posts because they are used more as a sign of *disagreement*.

Probably the best thing to forget it and move on. Having a question or answer downvoted happens to everyone once in a while.