# Finding the best tags to fit a question

Tags: discussion, tags, support

I have trouble finding the right tags for my questions. I tend to use tags which summarize my question. But I think tags should be more descriptive of the context that the question relates to.

At first glance, there might not be much of a difference, but here's an example on Meta: [Why is my answer downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39191/why-is-my-answer-downvoted)

The tags I chose: **[voting]**  **[discussion]**  **[meta-discussion]**  **[downvoting]**  **[style]**

The tags after an experienced user worked them over:  **[discussion]**  **[downvoting]**  **[specific-question]**

In my opinion the latter is clearly better.

How do you define your tags? Is there a rule of thumb for tagging? And if so, can you express the rule in one sentence? What would that be like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My one sentence: "Don't worry about it".

Tag questions the best you can, and then let the community decide what tags fit - the SOFU family of sites are collaboratively edited after all.

The example you gave is a perfect example that the system works. You're not necessarily going to know which tags tend to be used until you've been around a while, so let more experienced users re-tag things. Some day you'll have a better idea, and you'll be able to get stuck in to re-tagging.