# Who has downvoted me and why

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [So annoyed with no-comment, vindictive downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/so-annoyed-with-no-comment-vindictive-downvoting)

I have been downvoted for few answers of mine and the person who downvoted me did not leave any comments or reasons to say why I was downvoted. In such cases, how can I find out who has downvoted me and the reason for downvoting?

Comment: Just ask them... But be aware, some of us consider such comments to border on rude: avoid whining about the down-vote itself, or *demanding* a response - and do your best to figure it out on your own first...

Comment: also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39191/why-is-my-answer-downvoted

Comment: @fretje, both good questions, but not really dupes.

Comment: @Pop: I know, but still, it's a subject that has been discussed a lot before.

Comment: I completely understand wanting to know the reason *why*, but the fact that you seem more concerned with *who* downvoted you is a big red flag.  Why would you care?

Comment: @Bill - Sorry, my intention of knowing who downvoted me was to ask him for the reason. Ofcourse you are right that I dont need to know who downvoted me. Only thing I want is reason behind the downvote

Comment: I don't see a single downvoted question or answer on your profile to begin with.  What happened, you got one downvote on a post that already had a bunch of upvotes?  Who cares?

Comment: @Aarobot - I do have got lots of downvotes, but they were all coz of valid reasons and I do agree they were fair for my silly answers. But today I got a downvote for correct answer, atleast I dont see any fault in that. Other downvoted answers have been deleted by me since they were not correct

Comment: Alright, I understand, but read the tooltip on the downvote button - it says "this answer is not useful."  That's the implied comment with every downvote - someone didn't think your answer was helpful.  Maybe they thought it was too obvious to explain.  Or maybe, like so many of us, they're just tired of getting drawn into arguments with people who can't deal with criticism.  (Even if you'd have responded politely or revised your answer, there are *many* who prefer to argue 'til they're blue in the face.)

Comment: @Aarobot - point noted. Well said ;)

Comment: The canonical is *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)* (though this question is not strictly a duplicate of that one). On the other hand, the question that this question has been closed as a duplicate of, is itself closed as a duplicate of the canonical...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**No**

They probably just didn't like your answers. If it was a revenge down-vote run *(someone didn't like your answers and down-voted all your answer/questions in quick succession)*, the automatic vote detection scripts will pick it up and reverse it in 24 hours. To understand the detection scripts better you can visit the blog [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/). The actual process **will not be revealed** since it will defeat the purpose of the scripts.

If it wasn't, you will just have to live with not knowing. It's why we can down-vote **anonymously**.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is this revenge down-vote run? How does it find the revenge downvotes?

Comment: @Sachin. I have updated my answer. Also you don't have to @ someone when replying to a **question or answer they posted**, only if you want to reply to someone else.

Comment: @BinaryMisfit I don't know why my point down. What is the reason for that in StackOverflow?

Comment: The question was: "how can I find"... The answer "No"... What "no"? And, after that, the question could be not especially about an "answer", but on a question as well

Answer (score 8):

**You can't.**

**You can add a comment, asking for constructive feedback, but voting is anonymous by design.**

And if you ask for feedback, try to make sure your tone is, "I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer."

If your comment sounds like, "what's up with the down votes?", you'll likely attract even more of them.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid you can't find out who gave you the down vote. Votes are anonymous.  You'll just have to take it on the chin and move on.

I agree though, it is annoying when a comment isn't left.

EDIT:

Although it is annoying, it's really not worth getting worked up about.  If you take another look at your question/answer you will probably see why you got a downvote.  If you can't then don't worry about it.

After all you are only losing 2 rep - you can quickly and easily make that back.

Far too many people get hung up over the whole reputation thing.

Comment: yes constructive comments are always welcome, but without comments its just annoying

Comment: one time i put my soul into an answer and spent at least an hour on it - it was beautiful, elegant and an OOP's perfect dream - but it attracted a few down votes and i could never work out why. that's when i said 'for justice i must go to don corleone'