# Is there any way to know who has upvoted/downvoted on our questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)
>   [Who has downvoted me and why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63895/who-has-downvoted-me-and-why)

Hi All

I just wanted to know if there is any way to know who has upvoted/downvoted on our questions and answers?

Thanks

Comment: ohh sorry about this. I did not know this questions was asked before. My mistake ..